read double value from a file: std::invalid_argument after std::stod call
#include <iostream> 
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>


int main() {

    std::ifstream file("data.txt");
    std::string   line, numStr;

    // read first line
    std::getline(file, line);
    
    // read first value of first line
    std::istringstream lineStream(line);
    std::getline(lineStream, numStr, '\t');

    std::cout << "numStr= " << numStr << std::endl; // prints "numStr = "0.0014
    double num = std::stod(numStr); // <-- this failes
}


The file data.txt contains only one line with two values (see above picture), separated by tab.
When I run the above program using g++, I get the output
numStr= 0.0014
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::invalid_argument'
  what():  stod
Aborted (core dumped)

As you can see, the string is printed properly but for whatever reason, numStr.length() = 9, which is wrong since the string has only six chars.
Any idea what goes wrong here?
UPDATE:
After debugging, I figured out the file contains a BOM character at the beginning causing the issue. After re-saving without BOM, the code works as expected.

Clearly the string is not what you think it is. Print each character of the string, find out what is really there (or use a debugger).

Also when posting code to SO try not to rely on external files (we can't check that file to see if it contains what you say it contains). Instead use code like this line = "0.0014\t0.0000"; std::istringstream lineStream(line);. I suspect that code would then work, which would prove that the file does not contain what you think it does.

I guess I found the issue. The file contains a BOM character at the beginning.

Copy the content of your file and assign it into a std::istringstream. Then you can use that stringstream instead of your file (and test your code without being depdent on your filesystem) AND you can copy it here so we can also reproduce it.

Now you know there is a BOM in the file, you also have to be watchful for the wide characters that may come with it. That or resave the file in the native encoding (probably ASCII).

1.Trim whitspace- ensure numStr doesn't contain any leading space
2. Handle Errors- add exception handling to catch invalid strings

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
